# Hausdorff property of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

How can we prove Hausdorff property for real numbers?
I.e **If x and y are two distinct real numbers then there exist neighborhoods of x and y which are disjoint**.

*(I'm yet to learn topology)*

Can we just prove it using concept of neighborhoods?

Comment: Also you can take the idea from the real numbers and prove that every metric space is Hausdorff, just take the distance between the 2 points $d$ and consider the balls with center in those points and radius $d/2$

Answer (score 1):

If $x<y$ then $(x-1,\frac  {x+y} 2)$ and $(\frac {x+y} 2,y+1)$ are disjoint open intervals containing $x$ and $y$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\delta = \frac{1}{2} | x - y|>0,\ U=(x-\delta,x+\delta),\ V =(y-\delta,y+\delta).$

Clearly $U,V$ are open neighborhoods of  $x,y$ respectively.

Let's assume $U\cap V \neq \emptyset$ and derive a contradiction. Given $z \in U \cap V$:

$$|x-y| = |x-z +z-y| \leq|x-z|+|z-y|<2\delta=|x-y| $$
$$|x-y|<|x-y| $$

You've then reached a contradiction and proven $U\cap V = \emptyset$